How to Allocate Higher Resources for Kubernetes Pods During Startup and Scale Down After Stabilization?
I'm running a nonprod Kubernetes cluster with applications that require higher CPU and memory resources during the startup phase, but their resource requirements drop significantly once they are fully initialized and in steady-state operation.

if i setup resoruce limit and request it will conflict with other app start throwing error that CPU and ram is not available

I want to dynamically allocate higher resources during startup and then reduce the resource limits automatically or programmatically after the application stabilizes to optimize resource usage and costs.
What I've considered to test:

VPA
remove limit let the app running (in this way i can deploy multiple app ). i know its bad idea but its nonprod cluster and dont want to pay for extra node and i know nodes have enough CPU power to run the app its just that once application get initialize it take some high resources and then get stable..


What is the best practice for achieving this dynamic resource scaling during startup and stabilization?
Are there native Kubernetes features or tools that support this behavior efficiently?
Can Vertical Pod Autoscaler or any other autoscaling mechanism handle this kind of dynamic resource adjustment specifically for startup scenarios?


To address you issue, I would advise you to use one of these solutions:
In-Place Resource Resize which allows you to adjust CPU and memory for running applications without needing to restart them, which is particularly useful for managing varying resource needs during different phases of your app's lifecycle.
Kube Startup CPU Boost from Google which is a tool that temporarily increases CPU resources during the startup phase of your applications and then reduces them once the applications are stable.
Kyverno Policies can also be used to automatically adjust resources based on the application's status. For example, you can create a policy that reduces CPU resources once the application reaches a ready state.
Dynamic Resource Allocation DRA which can also be useed to manage various types of resources, including CPUs and GPUs, through ResourceClaims and ResourceClaimTemplates
